# Can we have a facebook.stackoverflow mini-site moderator election?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, election, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

The new Facebook partnership has been great and it has attracted a lot of new developers to the site. Unfortunately, it has also attracted a lot of people asking completely off-topic questions and a ton of duplicates. For example, I think there are 15 questions a day asking why their Facebook like button doesn't work.

The Facebook tags also aren't comparatively all that popular from an answerer/views perspective so a lot of questions aren't gathering the close/delete votes that are needed to keep the mini-site clean. The hours of 11PM-6AM PST are especially bad. I could spend 5 minutes pulling together a list of 20+ bad off-topic / low quality questions that need to be closed but haven't gotten enough votes from just the last 3 days alone (or just look at my close vote history).

The current moderators have done a decent job, but I think electing someone dedicated (and restricted) to the Facebook mini-site could be a huge addition to this new partnership (and to everyone who has to see low quality Facebook questions on their home page).

Comment: Can all of the [facebook] tagged questions be hidden from regular SO moderators and only shown to these new mods?  That would be *superawesome*.

Comment: @Won't until then I'll be sending a lot more to you because the community on the mini site isn't editing/closing them as needed.

Comment: Damn it[.](http://mofosummabeach.shi)

Comment: Sounds like this is a viable solution for the current FB subSO problem.

Answer (score 6):

Closing and deleting, as well as editing posts into shape are all things that can be done by ordinary community members, you do not need a moderator for that.

An alternative to your proposal would be an organized community effort to keep the facebook tags clean, similar to the [Posse on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/posse-nominations-for-aaronut). Get a bunch of people with enough rep to close and set them loose on the facebook tags. This spreads the work among different people, which means the users can take a bit more time than a SO moderator to edit questions into shape or explain why it had to be closed.

The community just scales better than a single moderator, and if you still don't have enough people to get the bad questions closed you can flag for a moderator to finish them off or delete them.

I doubt that your request will be implemented because there is no infrastructure in place for a tag-specific mod, you would need to be able to filter flags by tag and so on, and that is just not implemented because there is no need for that right now.

Comment: They could easily add the infrastructure to do - they filtered everything else on that site. I'll see what I can do about getting a community led group in the mean time and will start flagging them for mod attention until one or both of these are in place.

Answer (score 5):

We'll have more Stack Overflow moderator elections before the end of the year, and bring on between 3-5 new moderators (the exact amount depends on a few other variables).

Comment: Why not have one+ specific to the Facebook mini site though and filter the mod tools like everything else is filtered?