# Make better use of poor peoples close-flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

The 10k queue currently has ***and always has*** a large number of close question flags from people who don't yet have the vote-to-close privilege (3000 rep) **that never get checked**.

[image]

A while ago waffles asked the question [26,000 questions have close votes, now what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111734/26-000-questions-have-close-votes-now-what), and so here's what I think should now happen;

A flag-to-close from a <3000 rep user should lower the threshold of votes needed from >3000rep users to close the question. Without having data that's easily to manipulate, I'm not sure exactly *how much* this should lower the threshold, but I'm thinking something along the lines of 2 flags = 1 close vote.

I still think it's important that the close procedure still gets the attention of >3000 rep users, so I propose a limit on the number of close-vote-spaces that can be filled by <3000 rep users; e.g. flags-to-close can occupy 3 vote spaces, but 2 votes **must** come from >3000 rep users.

Comment: Are you calling us <3k-ers "poor people"?  I'm personally offended and will be writing a nasty letter to my congressman about this incident.

Comment: I don't think that **any** two flags should be automagically turned into close votes. Especially from a user who has not yet proven themselves knowledgeable enough to cast these votes and hence does not have the privilege to do so.

Comment: What about the people who have high "helpful flag" rates? I'm not over 3k on SO, but I can at least know that half the facebook and code dump questions are off topic @lix

Comment: @simchona - Oh defiantly - there are many active users on FSO who have a very firm grasp of things.  What becomes dangerous is when any 2 flags get put on steroids and transmogrify into a VTC...  But where do you draw the line?  What is defines a "high" count of helpful flags?

Comment: @lix ok then I agree with you then. I thought you were totally against this

Comment: @simchona - FSO is a darkcorner of [so]... The sheer volume of  Facebook customer support posts and off-topic questions IMO validate extra special attention as requested by one such [active user on FSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/can-we-have-a-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site-moderator-election).  We need a meta-facebook site to talk about issues there ;)

Comment: How about showing the queue to more people? I'm >3k but <10k, and I always have somewhere around 30-35 unused close votes at the end of the day. I'd gladly put those close votes to use, but I can't find the questions in need of closing.

Comment: @jadarnel27 The politically correct term is "reputation-impaired"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: It's "reputation-challenged," not "impaired."

Comment: Existing feature request to fix the FSO problems is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership).

Comment: @Juhana: I feel that's a much better solution to the problem than my suggestion! You'll have my +1 if you open a feature request!