# Facebook questions are weirdly ignored?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Am I extremely wrong, or are facebook question weirdly ignored?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-javascript-sdk?sort=newest&pageSize=30

Barely a single upvote for any question for weeks..... and the only questions that are having any attention are those which tagged as `javascript` before the `facebook`

Any reason?

Comment: Maybe there aren't a lot of knowledgeable Facebook developers spending time here?

Comment: The `facebook` tag has 2.8k followers, that's very little (and it's the most of all facebook-related tags). If you don't include a major language, chances are barely anyone will see your post.

Comment: but most of these question do indeed include major langs tags

Comment: Then I guess there aren't many people who are experienced with the facebook SDK. It's not like people will actively avoid the tag even when they know the answer..

Comment: What is weird about that? *//snark*

Comment: I used to have [tag:Facebook] in my ignored list pre moderator days. It was a great quality filter.

Comment: I clean a lot of Facebook questions out of the review queue every week, and there are a *lot* of really low-quality, non-programming, unanswerable questions in there.  These range from "Can't log in to Facebook" to the ten-thousandth variation of "How do I get all users who liked my post?" I think the overall low average quality causes a lot of people to avoid questions related to the tag.

Answer (score 9):

*I answer this question as someone who has spent more than a few hours cleaning up facebook related questions...*

The reason for so few upvotes on facebook tagged questions is because most facebook questions are quite crappy. Not only are the authors usually absolute beginners at using facebook APIs and possibly even coding, they are usually also beginners at StackOverflow - that usually shows in the quality of their questions.

The "facebook problem" has been discussed a [few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/can-we-have-a-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site-moderator-election) in the past because there were avalanches of bad questions coming in. It's got a little better over the last year or so, but I use the word "better" in a generous way - it's probably best described as *less bad*. The reason for the mess in the first place was an influx of inexperienced users. The lack of facebook representatives answering questions may have contributed - the questions would still have been bad, but at least they would have been answered.

**Is it something the community can do something about?** Yes and no. You can't stop the bad questions coming in, and down voting them simply makes the user (who was frequently transient anyway) disappear again, leaving their question unanswered and tumbling in the wind, waiting to be garbage collected. The community can help by tidying up those questions, so they may attract at least some answers. Gradually the tag will build up a population of experienced users who will eventually start to give back by answering questions instead of just asking them - when that happens the tag will start to slowly snowball and become more like the other mainstream tags.

Note that I'm not saying *all* facebook questions are bad - just a disproportionate amount of them. It's very slowly getting better - good things can take time.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer appear to make my question quite legit. Am I wrong? why the down vote then? And WHY, WHY people keep downvoting stuff without explanation? this is just absolutely useless. Any idea what wrong with my question?

Comment: @thefude Don't be concerned about the down votes, Meta works a bit differently. Your question is valid, someone simply disagrees with you.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot predict or control how the community will react to you post.

That being said, you can be more specific than only *Facebook*  if you want your post to stand out in the feed. I mean, Like Jeroen pointed out, 2.8K followers is nothing on SO so nobody will see it pass by if you only tag it Facebook.

Also, there are a lot of succesful facebook posts out there so I don't think the tag itself is a problem.